# confluence install cause 500 exception HibernateException

Tags: mysql, confluence

I currently use confluence and mysql to make personal wiki. However I have in `500 exception HibernateException`.

The log of confluence:

> Caused by: com.atlassian.confluence.tenant.VacantException: Confluence is vacant, a call to tenanted [public abstract net.sf.hibernate.Session net.sf.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession() throws net.sf.hibernate.HibernateException] is not allowed.
>         at com.atlassian.confluence.tenant.TenantGate$1.lambda$create$306(TenantGate.java:45)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)

What I have done:

1. confirm that the mysql connecter work correct. Details are in [Test mysql connerctor](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/troubleshooting-external-database-connections-658737195.html).
2. Reinstall serveral times, but the error appears too.
3. Google the problem and find it, but no anwse. See [openSession() throws net.sf.hibernate.HibernateException](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/22649509/confluence-fails-at-first-access-attempt-after-installation.)

Any helps are welcome！

Comment: did you get to solve this?!

Comment: I had solve the problem. The error was caused because I import other confluence mysql Database, so I just quit that plan.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest mysql-connector jar file and place it under /confluence/WEB-INF/lib/ with all the other libraries. Do a stop and restart your confluence instance.

I had the exact same exception openSession() failed, I upgraded my confluence instance from 5.1.3 to 5.10 then got into this exception, but after I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar, it WORKED.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can go wrong and cause this to fail.

First, make sure you have the *mysql-connector jar* in the proper place.

Second, go to your *HOME* directory for *confluence* and check `confluence.cfg.xml`. Look at these settings:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">[PASSWORD]</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/confluence?sessionVariables=storage_engine%3DInnoDB</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">confluenceuser</property>
```

Make sure the user and password for *mysql* are right. You can test in *mysql* using `mysql -u confluenceuser -p`.  Make sure the `url` is also right. In particular, the hostname `localhost`.